# flutter - Stopwatch error (rewind, forward)

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to make stopwatch for practice.
and i use datetime() function for deltatime.

play is work. but rewind, forward is not. i don,t know why T.T

```
  void startTimer() {
    setState(() {
      isRunning = true;
      isPaused = false;
      startTime = DateTime.now();
      previousTime = startTime;
    });

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 16), (t) {
      if (isRunning && !isPaused) {
        final now = DateTime.now();
        final frameTime = now.difference(previousTime).inMilliseconds;
        setState(() {
          elapsedTime = now.difference(startTime).inMilliseconds;
        });
        previousTime = now;
      }
    });
  }

  void rewindTimer() {
    if (isRunning && !isPaused) {
      final int newTime = elapsedTime - 5000; // 5 seconds
      if (newTime >= 0) {
        setState(() {
          elapsedTime = newTime;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  void fastForwardTimer() {
    if (isRunning && !isPaused) {
      final int newTime = elapsedTime + 5000; // 5 seconds
      setState(() {
        elapsedTime = newTime;
      });
    }
  }
```

maybe elapsedTime is not reason.

variable declaration is
elapsedTime is int.
previousTime, startTime is DateTime.